# MSbuild : read files with line feeds

Tags: msbuild

Using MSBuild, how to read a text file with carriage return/line feed and get each line content in a property?
The file goes like

```
Prod;2.13
Pre-Prod;2.14
Test;2.15
```

And I would like to get

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <_ProdVersion>2.13</_ProdVersion>
    <_PreProdVersion>2.14</_PreProdVersion>
    <_TestVersion>2.15</_TestVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

So far, i got this but it don't get where i can implement that line-feed splitting step and MSBuild Online Documentation is pretty light:

```
<ReadLinesFromFile Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'" File="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)/Resources/Others/MyFiles.txt">
    <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="MyItem" />
</ReadLinesFromFile>
<ItemGroup>
    <Lines Include="@(MyItem)">
        <Line_test>$([System.String]::Copy('%(MyItem.Identity)'))</Line_test>
    </Lines>
</ItemGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
    <_test>%(Lines.Line_test)</_test>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">           
    <_TestLine1>$(_test.Split(';')[0])</_TestLine1>
    <_TestLine2>$(_test.Split(';')[1])</_TestLine2>         
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Can you explain the result you actually want to get? And maybe also the higher level thing you want to achieve. Like: if you want to use a text file to get properties into msbuild, you could just as well use msbuild response files.

Comment: I made some updates...

Comment: Thanks, but how should the decision be made that `a` gets mapped to `_variable1`? Is it just because `b` happens to be the on first line? Or did you actually intend that `_variablea=b`?

Comment: The line "So far, i got this but it don't get where i can implement that line-feed splitting step..." should be edited. You are not splitting on the line feed; you are splitting on the semi-colon (;) within each line.

Comment: It seems you are trying to read the file and then create properties with values from the file and names based on the line number. You will probably need to use the [`CreateProperty` task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/createproperty-task?view=vs-2022) with your `@(MyItem)` (or `@(Lines)`) item collection so that you can name the properties. What do you do with the properties `$(_variable1)`, `$(_variable2)`, and `$(_variable3)`? Are those names hard-coded elsewhere?

Comment: I used these variables to create a class with MsBuild to manage version of the application versus the environnement. I edited the first message to add more context.

Comment: @stijn's answer is very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an easy solution using response files. It's easy, it's fairly standard and it's builtin so no manual processing required. It does require exact names (so not _Prod but _ProdVersion), but to be honest it seems a better choice to have the same name in your configuration file.

test.proj:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="ShowVersions">
  <Target Name="ShowVersions">
    <Message Text="_ProdVersion = $(_ProdVersion)"/>
    <Message Text="_PreProdVersion = $(_PreProdVersion)"/>
    <Message Text="_TestVersion = $(_TestVersion)"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

test.rsp:

```
/p:_ProdVersion=2.13
/p:_PreProdVersion=2.14
/p:_TestVersion=2.15
```

Called like `msbuild test.proj @test.rsp`, output:

```
FromResponseFile:
  _ProdVersion = 2.13
  _PreProdVersion = 2.14
  _TestVersion = 2.15
```

Or if you want the file to be used as you show, you could still transform it into a .rsp file using basic regex replacement. Well, and getting rid of the '-'. Powershell:

```
((Get-Content in.txt) -replace '(.+);(.+)', '/p:_$1Version=$2').Replace('-', '') | Out-File test.rsp
```

Now for the msbuild-only approach as you tried, add to test.proj:

```
<Target Name="ParseVersions">
  <ReadLinesFromFile File="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)/in.txt">
    <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="Versions"/>
  </ReadLinesFromFile>
  <!--Value is part after the ';', name is the part before it,
      but surrounded '_<name>Version' and without dashes in the name-->
  <CreateProperty Value="$([System.String]::Copy('%(Versions.Identity)').Split(';')[1])">
    <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="_$([System.String]::Copy('%(Versions.Identity)').Split(';')[0].Replace('-', ''))Version"/>
  </CreateProperty>
</Target>
```

And call `msbuild test.proj /t:ParseVersions;ShowVersions`. As you can see this isn't quite as readable as the other options. It could be split by first creating an item group, but that still would need the string manipulation logic.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. I just want to add that if the versions data file is not source controlled and is dynamically created and injected as part of a build pipeline, then, instead of creating the versions data file, the versions can just be defined either as environment variables or as properties on the MSBuild command line.

Comment: @JonathanDodds good point, that would be yet another way and indeed for CI usually the way to go

Comment: Thanks for your expanded and very precise answer. I adapted it and it works perfectly.